# NPP problems with config files

Tags: notepad++

Is there any way to stop Notepad++ from writing its config. files to every folder that I edit a file in.
I've tried installing with default options only and it still creates that folder with its config. files in it.

Thanks
Bob

Comment: Hmm. Notepad++ is *not* writing any extra files here. What is the name of the file it is writing?

Comment: in any folder when I edit a file it creates a folder named notepatt++ with 5 .xml files in it..

Answer (score 2):

When opening a file Notepad++ will create a folder named "Notepad++" in the current working directory. The folder will have 5 files config.xml, contextMenu.xml, langs.xml, shortcuts.xml and stylers.xml.

You maybe able to fix this issue by disabling the Cloud service option (available in recent versions of Notepad++). **Settings -> Preferences -> Cloud** *select* **"No Cloud"**, if a service is selected but disabled (grayed out) then it is a good indication that is the cause of the problem.

A common occurrence is to select the cloud option while a cloud service is installed and running. Then removing or disabling the service. Notepad++ will gray the radio box but wont un-select it (because the folder still exists at this point) at a later date if the local folder, that caches the cloud services files, is deleted then Notepad++ will revert to saving configuration files in the current working directory.